# Help with uninstalling GRUB

Tags: grub2

I have once installed Ubuntu on my Desktop. I dual booted it with Windows 10. My brother was messing with my disk manager and deleted my ubuntu drive. (un-installed it).The thing is GRUB remains and i want to get rid of.

BTW:I can boot into Windows 10.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and help us help you! Where did you install grub when you installed it?

Comment: Uninstalling grub won't solve the problem at hand. What you need is to reinstall the Windows bootloader, which will overwrite grub.

Comment: If you still can boot Windows, then it must be UEFI. http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi

Answer (score 0):

Grub is a `Boot Manager`.  You can install a different Boot Manager to replace Grub.  In your case, you can install the Windows Boot manager by running the Windows Install Boot.  When you run the Windows Install program it should detect Windows and give you the option to repair it.

If there is problems with the integrity of your Windows installation you'd have to get help from a group that support Windows.  Consider creating a new issue in a forum that supports Windows... http://superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

You'll need Windows 10 Installation or Recovery Media for that.

## Creating Recovery Media

This is **entirely optional** if you have Windows Installation Media

1. Boot into your Windows 10 install.
2. Open the start screen, type recoverydrive.exe and hit enter.
3. Plug in your USB Drive and click on next.
4. Choose the USB Drive from Available drives and click next.
5. Click on create.

## Installing Windows Bootloader

1. Restart your PC with the Windows installation media or Recovery media selected as the first boot device.
2. When Windows setup loads up, choose Repair your computer.
3. Click on Troubleshoot on the Choose an option page.
4. Choose Advanced Options and finally Command Prompt. Type the following command in the command prompt window:

> bootrec.exe /fixmbr`

5. After it is successfully done, restart your system and it should be good to go with Windows booting up normally

## Reference

https://www.techmesto.com/uninstall-linux-grub-dual-boot-windows8/